# Converting Geometry to Longitude/Latitude in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial-query

I am a noob to spatial data handling and I have 2 questions.

I uploaded a Shapefile to a Table in SQL Server through SHP2SQL executable and in a different Table through ogr2ogr.exe CLI. Even though the data is from the same shapefile, there are differences in the Geometry data in the 2 different tables as shown below. The 'ogr_geometry' has been uploaded through ogr2ogr CLI. And 'geom' has been uploaded through shp2sql application.

[image: Uploaded through ogr2ogr CLI]

[image: Uploaded through Shp2sql application]

If you may notice the data at the start differs as well as after '41' the strings start to differ. Which one is correct? I checked through prj file from the link "prj2epsg.org/search" and got this result

```
3347 - NAD83_Statistics_Canada_Lambert
```

My 2nd question is how do I check the geometry data against a set of latitude and longitude I have in a separate table? I am using below-mentioned query but it is not returning anything.

```
ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1
```

Please advise.

Comment: Geometry represents abstract 2D geometry on a plane, in arbitrary units. The system has no record of whether those units are in mm, meters or miles. Nor of where you might consider the origin to be located. If you want to talk in terms of latitude and longitude, you should be using the `geography` data type that represents locations on the earth.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have tried as per your suggestion but failed. I have updated question accordingly. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: And if I try to uplaod it through Shape2sql application, I get warning message. "Data seems to extend beyond the valid bounds supported by Geography type. Continue?" After clicking Yes, I get another warning: "Shape projection data claims it contains projected data, which is not supported by the Geography type. Continue?" I don't think that data I am dealing is compatible to be converted to geography type.

Comment: EPSG 3347 is a projected coordinate system. If you load it but tell the database it is in long/lat, you will get errors (like the out-of-bound error). If you really want it in long/lat then just transform it while loading:  `ogr2ogr -f ... xxx.shp .... -s_srs EPSG:3347 -t_srs EPSG:4326`

Comment: BTW, I removed the `oracle-spatial` tag since this has nothing to do with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, @AlbertGodfrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved it is by converting the EPSG 3347 to EPSG 4326 using QGIS. You can follow the below-mentioned link to see how to do that.

Afterward, I made sure to install QGIS 2.10 version as with the higher versions, there is a bug in the ogr2ogr.exe which doesn't allow the conversion.

Then, using the command line interface of ogr2ogr.exe, I converted the shapefile data into Long/Lat and loaded into the Local SQL DB table.

Then, I created a blank table "Spatial_Data" in the local DB.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\bin>ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=RBANSAL\SQL EXPRESS;database=MyDB;trusted_connection=yes" C:\Users\rbansal\Desktop\ShapeFile\MyShpfile.shp -nln "Spatial_Data" -progress
```

Hope this helps others.